# Apache Ignite C++ Thin Client: How do I put/get a byte array?

Tags: c++, ignite

What's the proper way to store a binary array in Ignite C++ and retrieve it?

I am using Apache Ignite C++ Thin client library. I read some examples and I can see you can specialize BinaryType template for custom classes [link](https://apacheignite-cpp.readme.io/docs/serialization), but I hope Ignite already has a class to handle standard buffer classes (e.g. std::vector).

Here's an example code of what I'm trying to do:

```cpp
void test() {
  ignite::thin::IgniteClientConfiguration cfg;
  cfg.SetEndPoints("127.0.0.1:10800");
  ignite::thin::IgniteClient client = ignite::thin::IgniteClient::Start(cfg);

  ignite::thin::cache::CacheClient<std::string, std::vector<char>> cacheClient;
  cacheClient =
          client.GetOrCreateCache<std::string, std::vector<char>>("BinaryCache");
  std::vector vector[10];
  cacheClient.Put("Key1", vector);
  cacheClient.Get("Key1");


}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no handle for standard containers. You should use custom class, which contains an array as its field and then write it using `BinaryWriter.WriteArray()` method.